# Amazon S3 file availability after upload

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I want to upload a file during a testcase and then immediately download it to verify the file has been uploaded. I use a key which is already uplopaded to S3.

When my upload is completed I do the download but somehow I get the previous version of this file.

My code looks something like this:

`final ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        objectMetadata.setContentType(binaryDataReference.getContentType());
        objectMetadata.setContentLength(data.length);
        objectMetadata.setContentEncoding(xmlEncoding.getCharset());
        s3Client.putObject(BUCKET_NAME, key, new ByteArrayInputStream(data), objectMetadata);
Thread.sleep(30000);  // this I've done because I thought its a timing issue.
S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(BUCKET_NAME, binaryDataKey);`

But the Object I get is not the one I just uploaded.

Do I need to do some thing or does anybody have go an idea what is wrnong with this approach ?

Comment: I have noticed this uploading and quickly downloading files to/from S3 using the web interface.  As a result, I have gotten in the habit of first downloading the file I'm replacing.  S3 consists of many physical serves, and I guess there are some timing issues getting the latest version advertised to all of them.  I don't know the specifics.

Answer (score 3):

It's just the way that [S3 works](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/):

> Amazon S3 buckets in the US Standard region provide [eventual consistency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency). Amazon S3 buckets in all other regions provide
>   read-after-write consistency for PUTS of new objects and eventual
>   consistency for overwrite PUTS and DELETES.

This means that after writing a new object you can always immediately read it as long as it is not in the US Standard region. Otherwise - i.e. if you are in the US Standard region or you are overwriting or deleting an existing object - you are only guaranteed that "eventually" the result of your action will be visible.

I once asked Amazon if after overwriting an object *and* succeeding in reading back the latest version, whether all subsequent reads on the same connection would be guaranteed to also return the latest version. That is, if I wrote version 2 and read version 2, would I never read version 1 again? They did not respond.

If you do require stronger consistency then [Google Cloud Storage provides read-after-update and read-after-delete consistency](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/concepts-techniques#consistency), though GCS was slightly more expensive than S3 the last time I checked.

Comment: There's no more comment about consistency in the linked FAQ. Here's the link to the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel